# Происхождение слова пи**а

Tags: этимология, обсценная-лексика

Расскажите, пожалуйста, о происхождении слова

> *пизда*.

Было ли оно заимствовано или является исконно русским?

Answer (score 1):

от слова писать, "с" перед звонкой "д" озвончается в "з". По аналогии с кривда, правда, враг (вражда) и т.п.

Comment: Всё бы хорошо, да _кривда, правда, вражда_ — производные либо от прилагательного, либо от существительного. А _писать_ — глагол.

Comment: @Aer согласно каким правилам этого сайта обсценное слово было зашифровано и скрыто?

Comment: в то же время, по-моему очевидна связь между глаголом пИсать и существительным пися/писька

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка см. https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/156/178412. Это скорее рекомендация.

Comment: @Aer кроме того, что это рекомендация, и она не подкреплена широким консенсусом, я думаю что она - сама по себе следствие излишнего пуританизма и ханжества некоторых носителей русского языка

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка давайте продолжим обсуждение в https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/156/178412 )

Answer (score 1):

**[Обсценная лексика в русском языке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82#%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)**

> П-да — от праиндоевропейского *pisd-eH₂*-  — «вульва», ср. лит. *piza* с
>   той же семантикой.

[Этимология](http://andrew-vk.narod.ru/public/obsc/obsc.html)

> Из праславянского *pizda, от кот. в числе прочего произошли: русск.,
>   укр., польск., чешск., сербохорв., словацк., словенск. pizda и др.;
>   восходит к праиндоевропейскому *pi-sd- / *pei-sd- «седалище, то на чём
>   сидят».

Другие версии - [по ссылке](https://a-kudryavets.livejournal.com/13145.html).